# Count total in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **orders table** and **line_item_table** in my database.
Please read following example

```
ORDER ID    LINE ITEM    Quantity
1           Banana        1.00 Kg
            Apple         1.50 Kg

2           Apple         2.00 Kg
            Banana        1.50 Kg
            Tomato        2.00 Kg

3           Potato        0.50 Kg
            Tomato        1.00 Kg
            Apple         2.00 Kg
```

I need over all quantity of every product likes this.

```
Banana  - 2.50 Kg
Apple   - 5.50 Kg
Tomato  - 3.00 Kg
```

and also likes this

```
Banana  - 1.00 Kg - 1
Banana  - 1.50 Kg - 1
Apple   - 1.50 Kg - 1
Apple   - 2.00 Kg - 2
Tomato  - 2.00 Kg - 1
Tomato  - 1.00 Kg - 1
```

How to do this in PHP MYSQL

Comment: Please can you show us the code you have so far so we can tailor our answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first case you can use this query. Also I would recommend you to not use spaces in table naming.

```
    SELECT line_item,sum(quantity) FROM `order` group by line_item
```

For second case

```
    SELECT line_item,quantity,count(quantity) as qty_cnt FROM `order` group by line_item,quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

First query will `GROUP`  items by name

```
SELECT [LINE ITEM], SUM([QUANITIY]) FROM [FRUITS] GROUP BY [LINE ITEM]
```

second will `ORDER` them by name and quantity

```
SELECT * FROM [FRUITS] ORDER BY [LINE ITEM], [QUANITIY]
```

Answer (score 1):

First case

```
SELECT line_item,sum(quantity) FROM `order` group by line_item
```

For 2nd case

```
SELECT line_item,quantity,count(quantity) as qty_cnt FROM `order` group by line_item,quantity
```